Interpolation of data with pandas
I have several measured values, each in a time series.
Time steps are unevenly distributed and also uneven between the data series.
I'm trying to interpolate each series into a fixed 10 second time step using Python and Pandas but interpolated values are only NaN.
This is a data snipped:
Timestamp,Value
2023-05-20T22:00:04.023Z,102
2023-05-20T22:00:14.033Z,100
2023-05-20T22:00:24.074Z,99
2023-05-20T22:00:35.484Z,99
2023-05-20T22:00:44.029Z,102
2023-05-20T22:00:54.054Z,100
2023-05-20T22:01:04.026Z,99
2023-05-20T22:01:14.029Z,103
2023-05-20T22:01:24.054Z,99
2023-05-20T22:01:34.022Z,98
2023-05-20T22:01:44.026Z,99
2023-05-20T22:01:54.062Z,100
2023-05-20T22:02:04.025Z,125

And this is the python script.
I'd say everything works like required, until the interpolate method.
import pandas as pd

Power_curr = pd.read_csv("pathtodata.csv",parse_dates=['Timestamp'])

# Convert the 'Timestamp' column to datetime format
Power_curr['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Power_curr['Timestamp'])

# timestamp is index
Power_curr.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)

# Find start end end, round to 10 s
start_time = Power_curr.index.min().ceil('10s')
end_time = Power_curr.index.max().floor('10s')

# Create new timestamp series
new_time_index = pd.date_range(start=start_time, end=end_time, freq='10s')

# Create new data frame and interpolate into new timestamps
Power_curr_interpolated = Power_curr.reindex(new_time_index).interpolate(method='time')

I believe that the result of Power_curr.reindex(new_time_index) is the problem.
It returns only NaN values, so there is no chance to interpolate these values. But why NaN?
Background information: Why this question?
One time series is the electricity consumption of a house, which is recorded on the electricity meter.
Another time series is the electricity generation of a PV system.
Both were recorded for over a year.
With this information, I would now like to calculate the degree of self-sufficiency that could have been achieved with a battery storage system.
What has been done so far?

I've tried different interpolation settings like 'linear' and 'nearest'

I checked, that new_time_index has the right type with
Power_curr['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(Power_curr['Timestamp'])

I've checked the installed pandas version: v2.2.2

I tried Power_curr_interpolated = Power_curr['Timestep'].resample('10s').mean()  instead of Power_curr.reindex(new_time_index).interpolate(method='time'). At least no NaN, but result looks wrong, as values do not change with changed timestamp:
pycharm watch

I've checked other posts realted to this issue like this: with no solution

Also checked this: looked promising
and got the believe, that the result of Power_curr.reindex(new_time_index) is the problem. It returns only NaN values, so there is no chance to interpolate anything. But why?



Please write a more descriptive title; see [ask] for tips on that. Say for example, "Why does reindexing a time series with an uneven index on an evened-out index result in all NaNs?"

The issue is that after reindex, you have no data left. Therefore there is nothing to interpolate.
You could first add the missing indices (while keeping the original ones), then interpolate, then keep only the desired indices:
Power_curr_interpolated = (Power_curr
                           .reindex(Power_curr.index.union(new_time_index))
                           .interpolate(method='time')
                           .reindex(new_time_index)
                          )

Output:
                                Value
2023-05-20 22:00:10+00:00  100.805794
2023-05-20 22:00:20+00:00   99.405736
2023-05-20 22:00:30+00:00   99.000000
2023-05-20 22:00:40+00:00  100.585489
2023-05-20 22:00:50+00:00  100.808778
2023-05-20 22:01:00+00:00   99.403730
2023-05-20 22:01:10+00:00  101.388883
2023-05-20 22:01:20+00:00  100.617556
2023-05-20 22:01:30+00:00   98.403491
2023-05-20 22:01:40+00:00   98.597561
2023-05-20 22:01:50+00:00   99.595257
2023-05-20 22:02:00+00:00  114.900130

Graph of data points:


It can be due to differences in precision or format.
I use the resample method instead of reindex for creating a new time index. This method is generally more reliable for time series data.
Power_curr_resampled = Power_curr.resample('10s').mean().interpolate(method='time')
print(Power_curr_resampled)

Output:
Timestamp                  Value     
2023-05-20 22:00:00+00:00  102.0
2023-05-20 22:00:10+00:00  100.0
2023-05-20 22:00:20+00:00   99.0
2023-05-20 22:00:30+00:00   99.0
2023-05-20 22:00:40+00:00  102.0
2023-05-20 22:00:50+00:00  100.0
2023-05-20 22:01:00+00:00   99.0
2023-05-20 22:01:10+00:00  103.0
2023-05-20 22:01:20+00:00   99.0
2023-05-20 22:01:30+00:00   98.0
2023-05-20 22:01:40+00:00   99.0
2023-05-20 22:01:50+00:00  100.0
2023-05-20 22:02:00+00:00  125.0


adding interpolate after mean won't change the data

@mozway Not for this data, but OP said it's unevenly distributed, so there could be chunks where 10 seconds are missing.
